# display table not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-7

i have this div perfectly positioned in IE8 and Mozilla Firefox

```
<div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 5%; padding-top: 13px;"></div>
```

but falling down in IE7. I have heard display table doesn't work in IE7 but the whole div is going haywire in IE7.

Comment: show html and css for the question.

Comment: <div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 5%; padding-top: 13px;"></div>

Comment: kindly update you question rather than putting it in the comment

Comment: its not taking the code in the question mate

Answer (score 1):

As you already said yourself what you are doing is unsupported in IE7
Here is the [w3Schools Document](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

You will need to use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) and handle it differently for IE7 or rethink your design

Answer (score 1):

Display table is not natively supported in IE7.

You could use an htc like [this one here](http://tanalin.com/en/projects/display-table-htc/) to realize it.